# Changing colour of as.factor ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = as.factor(z))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data=df,aes(y=predict(lmer(mymodel),df),newdata=df)
```

x and z are my explanatory variable with z being a factor. I then fit a linear mixed-effect model to my data, df.

How do I change the colour of `as.factor` ggplot in R? It's giving me RBG but I would like different colours. Your advise is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `scale_colour_manual` of `scale_colour_brewer`. In the first you can specify the colours manually and in the second you can choose one of the Colorbrewer palettes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define the colors as the post above suggests and reference the colors by name in the following table [r colors for ggplot](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/colour)

`scale_color_manual(name="Sex", values=c("dark grey", "black"), labels=c("Males", "Females"))`

where the name on the legend will be Sex and the labels will be male and female. Also, in the aes(x=year, y = number, color=sex)

Answer (score 0):

You can look for a good combination of colours in here http://colorbrewer2.org/

You will get the code for the corresponding colour you need (for instance "#2ca25f" as a kind of green or "#000000" as black) and you can add it in your code as following:

`ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = as.factor(z))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data=df,aes(y=predict(lmer(mymodel),df),newdata=df) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#000000",  "#2ca25f", ...)`

depending on the number of your z factors.

P.S. you can also write common colour names as "black", "white", etc. instead of the #code.